# Laravel - using HTML form instead of Collective HTML/Illuminate

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing a Laravel site and I am using HTML forms instead of Collective/Illuminate.

I used to have Illuminate prior to 5.0 but since it is not included anymore, I though it was not mandatory at all and that there would be no problems. However I keep hearing that I should use Collective.

Is it possible to use just HTML in Laravel or I need to use Collective?

Comment: Sure. There are some pages I use straight HTML on 4.2, and it works fine. Collective/Illuminate just makes things easier when formatting and passing in values. Just make sure you find a way to include your CSRF token in your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of Course it is possible, the removal of "Collective/Illuminate" is not because it has something wrong but just to give you feedom to decide how you want to proceed. So if you wish use plain HTML, otherwise use the package, the choise is all yours.